# ryan fait´s custom form script + reset select box via jquery

Tags: jquery, select, reset

i am using Rian Fait´s script for custom select boxes.[1](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)
the boxes have a small reset buttons on the right, which trigger 
the jquery script:

```
$('.reset_select').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('select').prop("selectedIndex", 0);
    return false;
});
```

This nicely resets the actual select box but does not update Text in the span-Tag.
(which replaces the select box for better styling)

does anyone have an idea!

thanks 
tobi

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug on the page to find the field where the actual label is for the select box, then you can add it to your script.